# WordPressPCL can't update and get posts but can create

Tags: c#, wordpress

I want to create/update/ posts through WP Rest API in a C# app with WordPressPCL.

I can't update a post, it's just throw an error:

**Failed to update the post: Exception thrown: 'WordPressPCL.Models.Exceptions.WPException**

And I can't catch it's always throws the same.

I have an "Actions" class where I have Authenticate function, CreatePost function and UpdatePost function.

I authenticate myself with basic auth.

```
        public static async Task<WordPressClient> Authenticate()
        {
            string apiUrl = "https://example.com/wp-json/";

            // Set the basic authentication credentials for your WordPress site
            string username = "usser";
            string password = "pass";
            // Create a new instance of WordPressClient and set the base URL
            var client = new WordPressClient(apiUrl);

            // Authenticate with the WordPress site using basic authentication
            client.Auth.UseBasicAuth(username, password);

            try
            {
                // Perform a simple request to check if the authentication is successful
                var user = await client.Users.GetCurrentUser();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    return client;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No such user!");
                }

            }
            catch (WPException wpex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to log in" + wpex.Message);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public static async Task<Post> CreatePost(WordPressClient client, string title, string content)
        {
            try
            {


                // Check if authentication was successful
                if (client != null)
                {
                    // Create a new Post object with the desired content
                    var newPost = new Post
                    {
                        Title = new Title(title), // Set the title of the post
                        Content = new Content(content), // Set the content of the post
                        Status = Status.Publish // Set the status of the post (e.g., "publish", "draft", etc.)
                    };

                    // Create a new post using the authenticated client
                    var createdPost = await client.Posts.CreateAsync(newPost);

                    // Check if the post was created successfully
                    if (createdPost != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Post created!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed to create the post.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to log in.");
                }


            }
            catch (WPException wpex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WPException Error:" + wpex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to create the post: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return null;
        }


        public static async Task<Post> UpdatePost(WordPressClient client, int postId, string title, string content)
        {
            try
            {
                // Check if authentication was successful
                if (client != null)
                {
                    // Get the post you want to update by post ID
                    var post = await client.Posts.GetByIDAsync(postId);

                    // Update the post properties
                    post.Title.Rendered = title; // Update the title
                    post.Content.Rendered = content; // Update the content

                    // Update the post in WordPress
                    var updatedPost = await client.Posts.UpdateAsync(post);

                    // Check if the post was updated successfully
                    if (updatedPost != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Post updated!");
                        return updatedPost;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed to update the post.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to log in.");
                }
            }
            catch (WPException wpex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WPException Error:" + wpex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to update the post: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Then I call the functions on button click:

```
private async void CreatePost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WordPressClient client = await Actions.Authenticate();

            if (client != null)
            {
                await Actions.CreatePost(client, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);

            }

        }

private async void UpdatePost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WordPressClient client = await Actions.Authenticate();

            if (client != null)
            {
                await Actions.UpdatePost(client, 399, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);

            }

        }
```

The CreatePost function is works well, but the UpdatePost function always throws this error (the post with ID 399 is exists)

**Failed to update the post: Exception thrown: 'WordPressPCL.Models.Exceptions.WPException**